# How to retrieve @attributes array value?

Tags: php, arrays

Can someone help me retrieve the value of the id from this array? Thanks

```
Array
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: What is the array name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a SimpleXML element.  The `@attributes` key is just how it's set internally.  Don't try to access it via that key.

You can just simply get the attribute by doing:

```
$id = (string)$element['id'];
```

<sub>Note: The cast to a `string` is needed because SimpleXML gives you a SimpleXMLElement object when you access something.</sub>